# Buffer geometry custom attribute material leaking into other objects

Tags: three.js

I'm making a visualization and want soft edged particles to represent data points.

I've gathered code from various examples and have something working except for a transparency issue.  I tried out the the new Stack Overflow snippet system and made a simple example of what I'm seeing.

As you'll notice, the sphere picks up the transparency from the particle system.  Is there a way to turn this off - in my application, this is a required feature.  I tried applying attributes to the material I use for the sphere but that didn't appear to help.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
var uniforms;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var ambient_light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333);
  scene.add(ambient_light);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 80;

  var num_particles = 5000;
  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  var positions = new Float32Array(num_particles * 3);
  var colors = new Float32Array(num_particles * 3);
  var sizes = new Float32Array(num_particles);

  for (var i = 0; i < num_particles; i++) {
      positions[3 * i + 0] = Math.random() * 100 - 50;
      positions[3 * i + 1] = Math.random() * 100 - 50;
      positions[3 * i + 2] = Math.random() * 100 - 50;

      colors[3 * i + 0] = Math.random();
      colors[3 * i + 1] = Math.random();
      colors[3 * i + 2] = Math.random();

      sizes[i] = 2.5;
  }
  geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
  geometry.addAttribute('customColor', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
  geometry.addAttribute('size', new THREE.BufferAttribute(sizes, 1));

  var attributes = {
    size: {
      type: 'f',
      value: null
    },
    customColor: {
      type: 'c',
      value: null
    }
  };

  uniforms = {
    color: {
      type: "c",
      value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff)
    },
    texture: {
      type: "t",
      value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("data:image/png;base64,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")
    }
  };

  var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

    uniforms: uniforms,
    attributes: attributes,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexshader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentshader').textContent,

    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    depthTest: true,
    depthWrite: false,
    transparent: true
  });

  var pointcloud = new THREE.PointCloud(geometry, shaderMaterial);
  scene.add(pointcloud);

  scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(50.0, 16, 16),
    new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({ })
  ))

  controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  controls.update();
}
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">
  attribute float size;
  attribute vec3 customColor;

  varying vec3 vColor;

  void main() {
    vColor = customColor;
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / length( mvPosition.xyz ) );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
  }
</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">
  uniform vec3 color;
  uniform sampler2D texture;

  varying vec3 vColor;

  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4( color * vColor, 1.0 );
    gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
  }
</script>
```

Edit:   WestLangley's suggestion in comments of turning on depth test results in this: (Don't know how to add an image to a comment so adding here)

[image: depth test set to true]

Comment: Is `shaderMaterial.depthTest = true` what you are looking for?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried but that breaks (some of) the particle transparency - couldn't add an image in a comment so added to the post.

Comment: Can you suggest anything else I can try @WestLangley? I've been experimenting with all kinds of settings and parameters in other parts of the set up code without any success.

Comment: Sorry. Study and experiment with all the combinations you can think of. At a minimum, you will learn a lot that way.

Answer (score 0):

The point cloud material attribute I was missing was depthWrite:false and as @WestLangley correctly said, depthTest: true;

I don't know how to version the embedded code so I updated it to work with these values.